# PHP / XPath -> Trying to scrape param name = "flashvars" in an object, but no result

Tags: php, xpath

Trying to scrape the video file off this website:`http://startv.com.tr/dizi/kiralik-ask/bolumler/sayfa/1/kiralik-ask-6-bolum`

I have scraped several websites before, but this one has all the  video details under the 'flashvars' attributes.  I tried the following code, but to no avail:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$titleQuery = $xpath->query("//object[@id='player_api']/param[@name='flashvars']/@value");

$title = $titleQuery->item(0);
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Nothing seems to be outputting... I just need the following to output so that I can then extract the url:

```
config={"key":"#$b7fea7222fcf06cf04b","canvas":{"backgroundColor":"#000000","backgroundGradient":"none","width":940},"clip":{"url":"http://startv.motiwecdn.com/startv/_definst_/mp4:startv/StarTV/Dizi/kiralikask/kiralikask6.mp4/manifest.f4m?e11b3501178b61b39327ddbaf0f1382abd05b815ab421995479746cc8000af6026681846e829f8353f49a7d2fb99ce29%26v%3D1","referanceID":"","PublisherId":"","provider":"dygprovider","scaling":"fit","test":"deneme","urlResolvers":null,"usePartition":1,"splitVideo":1,"partDuration":"20","currentPart":"1","nextPartCallBack":"changeParts","autoPlay":false,"forceAutoPlay":true,"live":null,"nextVideo":null,"suggestion":null,"adLib":[{"time":420,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D640x480%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FMID%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true},{"time":-1,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D640x480%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FPOST%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true},{"time":20,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D480x70%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FOVER%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true},{"time":0,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D640x480%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FPRE%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true}],"start":"0","duration":"0"},"play":{"opacity":1,"replayLabel":null,"label":null},"contextMenu":[{"Video URL’ini Al":"function()"},{"Geçerli Zamandaki Video URL’ini Al":"function()"},"DYG Player 1.0"],"plugins":{"dygprovider":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.dyg-video-provider-1.0.0.swf?12"},"f4m":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.f4m-3.2.10.swf?11v1s1"},"smil":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.smil-3.2.9.swf?v1"},"httpstreaming":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.httpstreaming-3.2.11.swf?31212321v111"},"hddn":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.13.swf?v1"},"bwcheck":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.bwcheck_httpstreaming-3.2.13.swf?1221v111","dynamic":true,"rememberBitrate":true,"bitrateProfileName":"startv","qos":{"frames":false,"screen":false},"netConnectionUrl":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flashlsFlowPlayer-0.4.0.7.swf?1","checkOnStart":true},"controls":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.controls-3.2.16.swf?11c1vs11"},"ima":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.ima-2.0.0.swf?1233x","test":"deneme2"},"comscore":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.comscore-1.0.0.swf?21","nameTag":"startv"},"partition":{"url":"http://img-dygassets.mncdn.com/player2/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.partition-1.0.00.swf?v11","buttons":{"overColor":"#ff0000"},"part":{"description":"index.php?part=","shareWindow":"_self"}}},"playerId":"player","playlist":[{"url":"http://startv.motiwecdn.com/startv/_definst_/mp4:startv/StarTV/Dizi/kiralikask/kiralikask6.mp4/manifest.f4m?e11b3501178b61b39327ddbaf0f1382abd05b815ab421995479746cc8000af6026681846e829f8353f49a7d2fb99ce29%26v%3D1","referanceID":"","PublisherId":"","provider":"dygprovider","scaling":"fit","test":"deneme","urlResolvers":null,"usePartition":1,"splitVideo":1,"partDuration":"20","currentPart":"1","nextPartCallBack":"changeParts","autoPlay":false,"forceAutoPlay":true,"live":null,"nextVideo":null,"suggestion":null,"adLib":[{"time":420,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D640x480%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FMID%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true},{"time":-1,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D640x480%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FPOST%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true},{"time":20,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D480x70%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FOVER%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true},{"time":0,"adURL":"https%3A%2F%2Fpubads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fgampad%2Fads%3Fsz%3D640x480%26iu%3D%2F37011203%2FWeb%2FStarTV%2FDiziler%2FPRE%26ciu_szs%26impl%3Ds%26gdfp_req%3D1%26env%3Dvp%26output%3Dxml_vast3%26unviewed_position_start%3D1%26url%3D%5Breferrer_url%5D%26description_url%3D%5Bdescription_url%5D%26correlator%3D1437913302143%26cust_params%3Dstar_cat%253D1410%2526playerType%253DflashPlayer%26ad_rule%3D0","useSkip":true}],"start":"0","duration":"0"}]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the object element, but that it is created dynamically with JavaScript. If you open the URL in your browser and *View Source*, you won't find the video object at all. You could use a headless browser to actually execute the JS, or better,  inspect the AJAX requests that are made on the site and figure out how the object is generated.